# Show custom table value in cart summary in magento2

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart, checkout-summary

I have a requirement to show a custom label with the value from the custom table inside the cart and checkout summary.

Example :
[image]

I have added the below code.

**Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider">
<arguments>
  <argument name="configProviders" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="totalmessage_config_provider" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Model\ConfigProvider</item>
  </argument>
</arguments>
```

**Vendor\Module\Model\ConfigProvider.php**

```
  <?php
   namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

   use Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface;
   use Vendor\Module\Helper\Data;

   class ConfigProvider implements ConfigProviderInterface
   {
     protected $_helper;

     public function __construct(Data $helper)
     {
      $this->_helper = $helper;
     }

     public function getConfig()
     {
       return [
        'totalmessage' => $this->_helper->getTotalMessage()
       ];
     }
   }
```

**Vendor/Module/Helper/Data.php**

```
 <?php
   namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

   use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
   use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
   use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;

   class Data extends AbstractHelper
   {
       protected $_checkoutSession;

       public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Session $session
        ) {
          parent::__construct($context);
          $this->_checkoutSession = $session;
       }

   public function getTotalMessage()
     {
    $quote = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote();
    if ($quote->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount() >= 100) {
       return __('custom message.');
    }
   return false;
 }
}
```

**Vendor/Module/Block/Message.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Vendor\Module\Helper\Data;

class Message extends Template
 {
  protected $_helper;

  public function __construct(
      Template\Context $context,
       Data $helper,
      array $data = []
    ) {
     parent::__construct($context, $data);
      $this->_helper = $helper;
   }

   public function getMessage()
   {
      return $this->_helper->getTotalMessage();
    }
}
```

**Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
 <body>
  <referenceContainer name="cart.summary">
    <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Message" 
   name="checkout.cart.summary.totalmessage" 
    template="Vendor_Module::message.phtml" 
    after="checkout.cart.totals.container" />
   </referenceContainer>
  </body>
</page>
```

**Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/message.phtml**

```
<?php if ($block->getMessage()): ?>
  <div class="total-message">
   <span><?php echo $block->getMessage() ?></span>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <body>
   <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
     <arguments>
       <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
          <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
              <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                  <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="itemsBefore" xsi:type="array">
                      <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="totalMessage" xsi:type="array">
                          <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/view/message</item>
                          <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">itemsBefore</item>
                          <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/message</item>
                          </item>
                        </item>
                      </item>
                    </item>
                  </item>
                </item>
              </item>
            </item>
          </item>
        </item>
      </item>
    </argument>
  </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

**Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/message.js**

```
  define(
  [
  'uiComponent'
 ],
 function (Component) {
   "use strict";
   return Component.extend({
  defaults: {
    message: false
  },

  initialize: function() {
    this._super();
    this.message = window.checkoutConfig.totalmessage;
  },

  hasMessage: function() {
    if (this.message) {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  },

  getMessage: function() {
    return this.message;
  }
  });
```

}
);

**Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/message.html**

```
<!-- ko if: hasMessage() -->
   <div class="block total-message">
       <span data-bind="text: getMessage()"></span>
   </div>
  <!-- /ko -->
```

This is working fine but it displayed after the Grand total, Can we move it above the Order Total?

How this can be done?

Please someone help me on this.

Comment: Can you please share code which you applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow this below way. I added value as static. You need to make it dynamic based on your requirement.

Create **checkout_cart_index**.xml at **app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/** and paste the below code :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.totals">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="block-totals" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="fee" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/view/checkout/cart/totals/customvalue</item>
                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">80</item>
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                         <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/checkout/cart/totals/customvalue</item>
                                        <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Value</item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Create **customvalue.js** at **app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/cart/totals/** and paste the below code :

```
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
define([
    'Vendor_Module/js/view/checkout/summary/customvalue'
],
    function (Component) {
        'use strict';

        return Component.extend({

            /**
             * @override
             */
            isDisplayed: function () {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Create **customvalue.js** at **app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/summary/** and paste the below code :

```
define([
    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/abstract-total'
],
    function (Component) {
        "use strict";
        return Component.extend({
            isDisplayed: function() {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Create **customvalue.html** at **app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/cart/totals/** and paste the below code :

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<!-- ko -->
<tr class="totals customvalue excl">
    <th class="mark" colspan="1" scope="row" data-bind="text: title"></th>
    <td class="amount">
        <span class="price" data-bind="i18n: '$50.00'"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
<!-- /ko -->
```

**Output :**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, how it works in checkout?

Comment: Can this be moved to before the order Total in checkout page? please share your screenshot of checkout